# Should I use the $.getJSON() method to load a JSON-LD file?

Tags: json, seo, google-search, schema.org, json-ld

I have a site that loads all the data from a JSON file. I'm converting the file to JSON-LD to make the data semantic and crawlable by search engines.

Right now I'm doing this and the site successfully loads the content:

```
$.getJSON('data.jsonld', function(data) { });
```

So the question is not whether I can do it, but whether I should. The JSON-LD documentation says that I should set the `type` attribute to `application/ld+json` when embedding JSON-LD in a HTML document, but doesn't say if using the `$.getJSOn()` method for loading a external JSON-LD file is a good practice or not. Is the file extension enough for Google to know that the file uses structured data?

Comment: As I don’t know JavaScript (assuming that this is JS … using jQuery, I guess?) very well: What does it do? Load the content from the file data.jsonld into … where?

Answer (score 0):

You definitely need to set the `type` attribute to `application/ld+json` when embedding JSON-LD in a HTML document, otherwise Google and other clients/search engines won't recognize it.

Not all crawlers are able to process dynamically injected content so if you need to support them as well and [not just Google](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/guides/intro-structured-data#markup-formats-and-placement), I'd embed it statically. Otherwise the dynamic injection is fine.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Markus. It's a huge JSON file (over 1MB) and for this project it's okay if Google is the only search engine that is currently able to process the content of the external JSON-LD, so I'll stick to the dynamic injection.

Comment: @Markus Are you sure Google crawlers will process dynamic injection? Our injection experiments fail. IOE only embedded JSON-LD is properly parsed.

Comment: Yes, I'm sure about that. See also the documentation at https://developers.google.com/search/docs/guides/intro-structured-data#markup-formats-and-placement. 1 MB of JSON-LD seems excessive though.. what data is this about? Might be that it is being ignored due to its size.